# Determining similarity between multiple text blocks

Tags: python, text, comparison, data-analysis

Is there a way to determine similarity of given multiple  text instances, maybe percentual or other way that can show how much common given text have with each other.

```
T1 = abcabcabc
T2 = xyzabcxyzabcxyz
T3 = abcxyzabc
```

Similarity would be something like:

```
*abc*abc* or maybe 66%
```

I can't be more specific at the moment.

If code is provided I prefer python but any script language or like is good, pseudo code as well or reference to problem solving sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are kinds of methods to measure distance between text .

Check [String metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) for more detail .

And there is a implement of [Levenshtein distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein) on `pypi` , I didn't try it myself .

There is another one on [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python)

While Levenshtein distance calculate the minimum step to convert one string to another , you may use `step / len(string)` to get the similarity percent of two string.